# Finding list of index corresponding to list of element of a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, list, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have a dataframe with millions of lines. I need to get the corresponding indexes of hundreds of thousands of elements that are present in the original dataframe.

I currently use this code:

```
df[df['processed_col'] == element.index[0]
```

to find the position of `'element'` into the whole dataframe.

Instead of doing a loop which is very long, is there a way to take a list like `element1, element2,..., elementN` as input, which would return a list of corresponding indices:

```
df[df['processed_col'] == [element1, element2, ..., elementN].index[0]
```

Comment: Hmmm, you need `df[df['processed_col'].isin([element1, element2,..., elementN])].index[0]`

Comment: Sorry your question is unclear are you asking for `df[df['processed_col'].isin(some_list)].index`?

Comment: @jezrael I think the OP wants the index values where the values exist, `index[0]` will return the first index value

Comment: Yes, if need only first value, use `index[0]`, if need all values, use `index`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) if find first value of index:

```
df[df['processed_col'].isin([element1, element2,..., elementN])].index[0]
```

or if want all values of index, remove `[0]` only:

```
df[df['processed_col'].isin([element1, element2,..., elementN])].index
```

If need convert to list use [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.tolist.html):

```
df[df['processed_col'].isin([element1, element2,..., elementN])].index.tolist()
```